# WCF returns empty custom collection type

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, observablecollection

As you know `ObservableCollection` has no `AddRange` extension method. So we have added custom collection which is derived from `ObservableCollection`:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public CustomObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public CustomObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public CustomObservableCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        foreach (var item in range)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        this.Items.Clear();

        AddRange(range);
    }
}
```

Service reference has a default collection type of `ObservableCollection`. That means that when you add a service reference you see a result in client as `ObservableCollection`. We have changed this by modifying `Reference.svcmap` file:

```
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="BusinessModel.Common.CustomObservableCollection`1" Category="List" />
</CollectionMappings>
```

Now I can see that my service is returning `CustomObservableCollection` to the client.

But the problem is **it returns empty collection**. I know there is data in custom collection before the service returns, but my `silverlight` client receives empty set. Has anyone got an idea what can be the problem?

We have tried to add an extension, but the thing is that extension method raises collection change notifications for each element and thus our `silverlight` application is simply dying on large collections. That's why we use `subclassing` to raise event only once.

Comment: Why don't you just add an `AddRange` Extension Method for the baseclass library type `ObservableCollection`? To me that seems to be easier.

Comment: @Martin, of course we have tried that, but the thing is that it raises collection change notifications for each element and thus our silverlight app is simply dead on large collections. That's why we use subclassing to raise event only once

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable now.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the attribute `[CollectionDataContract]` from the class and now everything works.